# What causes the warning 'rpc_zdelay_work_func => 0'

Tags: android

When I run my application on either Android emulator or an actual device, the LogCat output is filled withing literally seconds with this message in yellow color

> 01-26 10:50:42.550: WARN/PrintK(24):
>   rpc_zdelay_work_func => 0

This started happening pretty recently and I don't even know what to look at, I mean this warning, supposedly it warns me about something, doesn't it?

A bit about the app features:
so the application uses a lot of communication over XMPP (uses pretty many threads for that), it has a map, uses the GPS, I draw some stuff on the screen myself from the code, I use some custom png graphics, the layouts of the screens are made with merge, Relational and Linear layouts. To me it seems quite a natural app, without any fancy stuff...

OK, this is really weird, today that warning is just gone! It disappeared like never existed. The only difference I can think of is that I unplugged the usb cable.

Comment: Can't find "rpc_zdelay_work_func" in the source... what emulator and what device are you running on? Is it possible it's coming from your app rather than the platform?

Comment: Oh man, thanx for reply! I use a few virtual devices (all of them produce the same thing) and a couple hardware devices (Dell Streak, Samsung Galaxy Tab). It is possible that my code causes it, but not that it produces this message. The warning looks like a C one to me.

Comment: It does look pretty low level. The common thread seems to be SIP... are you doing anything with SIP?

Comment: ok, i added a smallish description of the features in the app. Not sure this is of any help though.. I agree with Reuben it looks like a pretty low level. And regarding SIP, I have no clue tbh, at least I'm not aware that something I use does something with SIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintK() is a kernel method similar to Log().  It is used by kernel developers the same way Log is used by java developers.  The message rpc_zdelay_work_func =>0 is something the developer wanted logged.  It could be that the kernel is being taxed too heavily at a certain time and is reporting that the kernel is slowing down, or it could be that the usb comm was spazzing out the kernel.  What ever the cause, it was not coming from your app.

Comment: Alright, that's pretty much what I expected to hear. Also, since this message is gone with no obvious reason as well as no dramatic changes to the code, I'd assume that it wasn't coming from my code. Thank you for your input.